# Extending the scale of an axis

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have generated the following histogram in R:

[image: Histogram]

I generated it using this `hist()` call:

```
hist(x[,1], xlab='t* (Transition Statistic)',
     ylab='Proportion of Resamples (n = 10,000)',
     main='Distribution of Resamples', col='lightblue',
     prob=TRUE, ylim=c(0.00,0.05),xlim=c(1725,max(x[,1])+10))
```

Plus the following `abline()`:

```
abline(v=1728,col=4,lty=1,lwd=2)
```

That vertical line indicates the actual location of a test statistic, which I am comparing to the results of permutation samples.

My question is this: as you can see, the x scale does not extend back to the vertical line. I would really like it to do so, because I think it looks odd otherwise. How can I make this happen?

I have already tried the `xaxs="i"` parameter, which has no effect. I have also tried making my own axis with `axis()` but this requires making both axes again from scratch, and the results don't look that great to me. So, I suspect there must be an easier way to do this. Is there? And, if not, can anyone suggest what `axis()` command might work well, assuming I want everything to look basically the same, but with the longer x scale?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since R is using gaps of 20 for the x-axis here, you can get the extension you want using 1720 rather than 1725 for the lower limit , i.e. with `xlim=c(1720,max(x[,1])+10)` which would produce something like

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The usual R plot draws a frame around the plot. To add this, do:

```
box()
```

after the plot.

If that isn't what you want, you need to suppress axis plotting and then add your own later.

```
hist(...., axes = FALSE) ## .... is where your other args go
axis(side = 2)
axis(side = 1, at = seq(1730, 1830, by = 20))
```

That won't go quite to the vertical line but may be close enough. If you want a tick at the vertical line, choose different tick marks, e.g.

```
axis(side = 1, at = seq(1725, 1835, by = 20))
```